# Is there a way to check approval responses separately?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a flow that uses an approval block, sends the approval request to different many users and waits until they all have checked it. But I need to check in any time who has answered and who has not. Is there a way to do that? Maybe an API or even a way outside MS Flow?

Comment: How are you wanting to check who's responded or not? Manually? Get an email notification at any given time? Etc. We need more info.

Comment: The problem was that, when an approval reaches its time limit and not all of the assigned people had sent their responses, I couldn't get the list of people who answered the approval on time.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend as people send approvals-- you update a SharePoint list with information (e.g. have columns for each level of approval and harvest the name of the person who did the approval and put it in the SP column). However, you're using past tense here... is the issue resolved for you already?

Comment: I'll tell my boss about this solution, but I think the problem is on hold, so for now, thank you for your comments :D, if there is any change, I'll tell you (if you're interested obviously)